# How is this object's destructor being called two times?

Tags: c++, c++17

Can someone please explain how test1 is getting destroyed 2 times? Compiled with Visual Studio C++17

```cpp
class test {
public:
    test(int val):val_(val) {
        cout << "test" << val_ << "constructor called\n";
    }
    ~test() {
        cout << "test" << val_ << " destructor called\n";
    }
    int val_;
};

int main() {
    auto t2 = test(2);
    {
        auto t1 = test(1);
         swap(t1, t2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test2constructor called

test1constructor called

test1 destructor called

test2 destructor called

test1 destructor called
```

Comment: You should print the value of `this` along with the message.  You will see that you are not tracking all of the possible constructors that are being called, like the copy constructor.

Comment: Add this friend function to `test`: `friend void swap(test& a, test& b) { swap(a.val_, b.val_); }`  Otherwise you'll get the possibly less efficient generic one, which copies into a temp, to perform the swap.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks. Just tested with explicitly declared copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general implementation of `swap` is as follows:

```
template<typename T> 
void swap(T& x, T& y) {
  T tmp = std::move(x);
  x = std::move(y);
  y = std::move(tmp);
}
```

There is a temporary variable `tmp`, which is destroyed when it leaves the scope of `swap`.

Since it is initialized by `x` at the beginning, its value is `1`, and when it is assigned to `y` again, `std::move` will not change its value, so its value is still `1`.